# Create footer in html for bottom of document not body

Tags: html, css

I'm working on site that have header , content and footer just like other sites , my Problem is when creating the footer it's not stick in document bottom and stick at the bottom of body in html , Here the picture show what I mean :
[image]
if I use fixed position for footer in css the result show me like this:
[image]

but the main problem is , if Added footer after last div in body I get white space after it , and if use position fix , the footer show in bottom 0 , for better understanding I have one more picture :
[image]
as you see in this picture footer fixed in bottom of user view not document , so that all I need is get footer attached to end of document after all contents no body or user view.

```css
/*End FontFamily*/
/*===========================================================================*/
/*General style*/
body{
    font-family: Vazirmatn;
}
.shadow{
 box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.24) 0px 3px 8px;   
}
.cardbox{
    background-color: white;
    margin-bottom: 16px;
}
hr{
    color: lightgray;
}
a{
    text-decoration: none;
}
.pull-right {
    float: right;
}
.pull-left {
    float: left;
}
.green{
    color: green;
}
.red{
    color: red;
}
.gray{
    color: darkgray;
}
.darkgreen{
    color: darkgreen;
}



/*end General Style*/
/*===========================================================================*/
/*breadcrumb*/
/* Style the list */
ul.breadcrumb {
  padding: 8px 16px;
  list-style: none;
    height: 24px;
    width: 100%;
    font-family: Vazirmatn;
}

/* Display list items side by side */
ul.breadcrumb li {
  display: inline;
  font-size: 10px;
}

/* Add a slash symbol (/) before/behind each list item */
ul.breadcrumb li+li:before {
  padding: 8px;
  color: lightgray;
  content: "/\00a0";
}

/* Add a color to all links inside the list */
ul.breadcrumb li a {
  color: lightgray;
  text-decoration: none;
}

/* Add a color on mouse-over */
ul.breadcrumb li a:hover {
  color: #01447e;
  text-decoration: underline;
}
/*End breadcrumb*/
/*===========================================================================*/
/*side blocks*/
/*--- Sidebar ---*/

.sidebarblock {
    background-color: #ffffff;
    border-radius: 2px;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 2px #c9cccd;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.sidebarblock h3 {
    color: #363838;
    font-size: 16px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 20px;
    font-weight: 600;
}

.sidebarblock .divline {
    height: 1px;
    line-height: 1px;
    border-bottom: solid 1px #f1f1f1;
}

.sidebarblock .blocktxt {
    padding:20px;
}
.sidebarblock .blocktxtlight{
    font-size: 12px;
     padding:4px 20px 4px 20px;
}
ul.cats li {
    list-style: none;
    display: block;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    line-height: 30px;
}

ul.cats {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

ul.cats li a {
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #363838;
    line-height: 30px;
}

ul.cats .badge {
    background-color: #bdc3c7;
    font-size: 12px;
    color: #ffffff;
    margin-top: 7px;
}


.sidebarblock .blocktxt {
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #363838;
}


.sidebarblock .blocktxt .smal {
    font-size: 12px;
}

.chbox {
    width: 50px;
}

table.poll {
    width: 100%;
}

.progress-bar.color1 {
    background-color: #9b59b6;
}

.progress-bar.color2 {
    background-color: #3498db;
}

.progress-bar.color3 {
    background-color: #e67e22;
}

.progress-bar {
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #ffffff;
    line-height: 31px;
    text-align: left;
    padding-left: 10px;
    box-shadow: none;
}


.progress {
    background-color: #ecf0f1;
    height: 31px;
    border-radius: 2px;
    box-shadow: none;
}



.poll label {
    margin-bottom: 0;
    margin-left: 20px;
}

.poll input[type="radio"] {
    display:none;
}

.poll input[type="radio"] + label {
    display:inline-block;
    width:31px;
    height:31px;
    background: url(radio.jpg) 0 0 no-repeat;
    vertical-align:middle;
    cursor:pointer;
}

.poll input[type="radio"]:checked + label {
    background: url(radio.jpg) -31px 0 no-repeat;
}

td.chbox {
    vertical-align: top;
}

/*end side blocks*/
/*===========================================================================*/
/*Tickets review*/
.beforepagination {
    margin-bottom: 0;
}
.ticket {
    background-color: #ffffff;
    border-radius: 2px;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 2px #c9cccd;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    padding: 8px
}
.ticket .userinfo {
    padding: 15px 0 15px 0;
}

.ticket .avatar {
    margin-right: 5px;
}
.ticket .co-ownership {
    width: 100%;
    border-top: solid 1px #f1f1f1;
    margin-top: 12px;
    padding-top: 7px;
    margin: auto;
     text-align: center;
}

.ticket .posttext {
     text-align: justify;
  text-justify: inter-word;
    padding-right: 8px;
    font-size: 14px;
    margin-left: 8px;
}
.ticket h2 {
    color: #363838;
    font-size: 18px; 
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.ticket .comments {

    padding: 18px 0 25px 0;
    text-align: center;
}

.ticket .comments .commentbg {
    background-color: #bdc3c7;
    border-radius: 2px;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 6px 8px;
    color: #ffffff;
    font-size: 10px;
    position: relative;
}

.ticket .comments .commentbg .mark {
    width: 10%;
    height: 11px;
    background-color: #bdc3c7;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 36%;
    margin-bottom: -5px;
    transform:rotate(45deg);
    -ms-transform:rotate(45deg); /* IE 9 */
    -webkit-transform:rotate(45deg); /* Opera, Chrome, and Safari */
}

.ticket .views {
    color:#9da6aa;
    font-size: 10px;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 29px;
}

.ticket .views i {
    font-size: 10px;
}

.ticket .time {
    color:#9da6aa;
    font-size: 12px;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 29px;

}

.ticket .time i {
    font-size: 14px;
}

.ticket .ticketinfo {
    border-right: solid 1px #f1f1f1;
}
.avatar {
    position: relative;
}
.avatar img {
    border-radius: 50%;
    border: 0;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
.avatar .online {
    background-color: green;
}
.avatar .offline {
    background-color: lightgray;
}
.avatar .status {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 12px;
    height: 12px;
    line-height: 12px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    border: solid 2px #ffffff;
}


.postinfobot {
    border-top: solid 1px #f1f1f1;
    line-height: 32px;
    padding: 0 0 0 0;
}


.postinfobot .information {
    margin-left: 18px;
    font-size: 9px;
    color: #bdc3c7;
}

.postinfobot .information i {
    font-size: 12px;
    color: #bdc3c7;
    padding-right: 8px;
}

.toTheTicket {
  display: flex;
  height: 100%;
  align-items: center;
margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.toTheTicket i {
  line-height: normal;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
    padding-left: 16px;
}
.tagsintickets{
    padding: 8px 20px 8px 20px;
}

/*End Tickets review*/
/*===========================================================================*/
/*--- Pagination ---*/
.pagination {
  display: inline-block;
    font-size: 9px;
    padding: 8px 0 0 0;
}

.pagination a {
  color: black;
  float: left;
  padding: 4px 8px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.pagination a.active {
  background-color: lightblue;
  color: white;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.pagination a:hover:not(.active) {
  background-color: #ddd;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
/*--- End Pagination ---*/
/*===========================================================================*/
/*Menu*/
.main_menu{
    width: 100%;
    height: 48px;
    background-color: white;  
    margin-bottom: 8px;
}
.searchbox{
    height: 32px;
}
.main_menu .wrap{
    margin-top: 8px;
    height: 32px;
    margin-right: 8px;
    width: 100%;
}
.main_menu .wrap input{
    width: 40vw;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 995px) {
.main_menu .wrap input{
    width: 20vw;
}
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 765px) {
.main_menu .wrap input{
    width: 45vw;
}
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 575px) {
.main_menu .wrap input{
    width: 65vw;
}
}

.avt {
    height: 48px;
}

.avt button {
    margin-top: 8px;
    height: 32px;
    border: none;
    box-shadow: none;
    color: #ffffff;
    font-size: 12px;
    padding-left: 16px;
    padding-right: 16px;
    background-color: #1abc9c;
}

.avt .btn-primary:hover, 
.avt .btn-primary:focus, 
.avt .btn-primary:active, 
.avt .btn-primary.active{
    background-color: #1abc9c;
    border: none;
    box-shadow: none;
}

.env {
    height: 32px;
    margin-top: 8px;
    font-size: 18px;
    color:#cfd5d7;
    line-height: 38px;
    padding: 0 20px;
}

.main_menu .avatar {
    margin-top: 8px;
    margin-left: 8px;
}

.main_menu .avatar img {
    border-radius: 50%;
}

.dropdown.avatar .status {
    right: 14px;
}

/*End Menu*/
/*===========================================================================*/
/*header description*/
.headerDescription{
    padding: 20px;
}
.headerDescription h4{
    font-weight: 500;
}
.headerDescription p {
         text-align: justify;
  text-justify: inter-word;
    font-size: 14px;
}

/*End header description*/
/*===========================================================================*/
/*footer*/
.footer{
    width: 100%;
    padding: 20px;

}
/*end footer*/
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html dir="rtl">
    
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
         <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
        <title>دمو نظام حل مسئله</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="plugins/jquery/jquery-3.6.3.min.js"></script>
         <script type="text/javascript" src="plugins/bootstrap/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="plugins/bootstrap/bootstrap.rtl.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rbsA2VBKQhggwzxH7pPCaAqO46MgnOM80zW1RWuH61DGLwZJEdK2Kadq2F9CUG65" crossorigin="anonymous">
         <link rel="stylesheet" href="mian.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="plugins/fontawesome/css/all.min.css">

        
        
        
        <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="57x57" href="/favicon/apple-icon-57x57.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="60x60" href="/favicon/apple-icon-60x60.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="72x72" href="/favicon/apple-icon-72x72.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="76x76" href="/favicon/apple-icon-76x76.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="114x114" href="/favicon/apple-icon-114x114.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="120x120" href="/favicon/apple-icon-120x120.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="144x144" href="/favicon/apple-icon-144x144.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="152x152" href="/favicon/apple-icon-152x152.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="180x180" href="/favicon/apple-icon-180x180.png">
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="192x192"  href="/favicon/android-icon-192x192.png">
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="32x32" href="/favicon/favicon-32x32.png">
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="96x96" href="/favicon/favicon-96x96.png">
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="16x16" href="/favicon/favicon-16x16.png">
<link rel="manifest" href="/favicon/manifest.json">
<meta name="msapplication-TileColor" content="#ffffff">
<meta name="msapplication-TileImage" content="/favicon/ms-icon-144x144.png">
<meta name="theme-color" content="#ffffff">
        
        
        
        
        
        
    </head>
    <body style="background-color: aliceblue">
<!--main body-->
<!--menu-->
        <div class="main_menu shadow">
            
            
      <div class="container">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="d-none d-xs-none d-sm-none d-md-block col-1 logo  d-flex justify-content-center"><a href="index.html"><img src="favicon/android-icon-48x48.png" alt=""></a></div>
                        
                        
                        
                        <div class="d-none d-sm-none d-md-block col-sm-3 col-lg-2  avt  d-flex justify-content-center">
                            <div class="stnt pull-left">                            
                                <form action="03_new_topic.html" method="post" class="form">
                                    <button class="btn btn-primary">طرح پرسش جدید</button>
                                </form>
                            </div>
     
                            <div class="clearfix"></div>
                        </div>
                        
                        
                        <div class="col-sm-auto col-lg-9 col-xs-12 d-flex justify-content-center">
                            <div class="avatar pull-right dropdown">
                                <a data-toggle="dropdown" href="#"><img src="avatar2.jpg" height="32" width="32" ></a> 
                                <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                                    <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">My Profile</a></li>
                                    <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-2" href="#">Inbox</a></li>
                                    <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-3" href="#">Log Out</a></li>
                                    <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-4" href="04_new_account.html">Create account</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                            
                            <div class="wrap">                                
                                <form action="#" method="post" class="form">
                                    <div class="pull-right txt">
                                        <input type="text" class="searchbox form-control" placeholder="[جستجو...]">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="pull-right">
                                        <button class="btn btn-default" type="button"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></button>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="clearfix"></div>
                                </form>
                            </div>
                            
                               <div class="env pull-left d-none d-sm-block"><a href="#"><i class="gray fa-solid fa-bell"></i></a></div>
                        </div>
                        
                    </div>
                </div>
            
            
            
            
        </div>
<!--end menu        -->
<div class="container">
<!--    breadcrumb-->
        <div class="row">
        <ul class="breadcrumb">
            <li><a href="#">نظام حل مسئله</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">مسائل مطرح شده</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">خدمات مشترکین</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
<!--        end breadcrumb-->
    <!--    main content row-->
    <div class="row">

              <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-8">
                  
                  <div class="headerDescription cardbox shadow">
                  <h5>سوالات برچسب شده [خدمات مشترکین]</h5>
                      <p>این ستاد وظیفه دارد که جهت پاسخگویی صحیح و رضایت حال مشترکین محترم با ادارات تابعه خود هماهنگ شده و درخواست‌ها و پیشنهاداتی که به خدمات مشترکین در ستاد ارجاع میگردد براساس مقررات و آئین نامه تکمیلی تعرفه‌های برق آنرا تا حصول نتیجه پیگیری نماید کارهایی که در این ستاد انجام میشود بصورت خلاصه بشرح ذیل میباشد:</p>
              <p>۱ - رسیدگی به شکوائیه جهت اشتراکهای عادی و دیماند<br />
۲ - بررسی تعدیلات در بخش عادی و دیماند<br />
۳ - نظارت بر فروش انشعابات عادی ودیماند در شهرستانهای تابعه شرکت<br />
۴ - بازرسی موردی و اتفاقی از ادارات مشترکین در شهرستانهای تابعه شرکت<br />
<hr>
                      <div class="filter">
                      <div class="btn-group" role="group" aria-label="Button group with nested dropdown">
                           <button type="button" class="btn"><span class="fa-solid fa-eye fa-lg" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                               دنبال کردن</button>
                          <button type="button" class="btn"><span class="fa-regular fa-clock fa-lg" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                               تازه ها</button>
                          <button type="button" class="btn"><span class="fa-solid fa-chart-line fa-lg" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                               فعال ترین</button>

                          
</div>
                      </div>
                  </div>

                  
   
                  
                  
                      <div class="ticket beforepagination shadow cardbox">
        
                                <div class="topwrap">
                                    
                                      <div class="row">
                                          
                                    <div class="col-md-1 col-sm-2 d-flex justify-content-center">
                                    <div class="userinfo pull-right">
                                        <div class="avatar">
                                            <img src="avatar4.jpg" alt="">
                                            <div class="status offline">&nbsp;</div>
                                        </div>

                                        <div class="co-ownership">
                                          <i class="fa-regular fa-circle-check gray"></i>                                         
                                          <i class="fa-solid fa-lock green"></i>                                                                        
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                        </div>
                                           <div class="col-md-10 col-sm-8">
                                    <div class="posttext pull-right">
                                        <h2><a href="#">جا به جایی واحد مالی (بسته شده)</a></h2>
                                        <p>از لحاظ استقرار موقعیت واحد مالی اصلاً جالب نیست و فکر می کنم باید در جای دیگه ای مستقر بشوند ، بنظرم به قسمت ساختمان شماره 5 بروند بهتر است.یا شاید هم در جای دیگری</p>
                                    </div>
                                          </div>
                                          <div class="col-md-1 col-sm-2 p-0 pb-2 d-flex justify-content-center">
                                            <div class="toTheTicket"><a href="#"><i class="fa-regular fa-eye-slash fa-2x gray"></i></a></div>
                                          </div>
                                          
                                          </div>
                                                                        <div class="tagsintickets">

<span class="badge bg-light text-dark">صنعت برق</span>
<span class="badge bg-light text-dark">ساختارسازمانی</span>
<span class="badge bg-light text-dark">واحدسازمانی</span>
<span class="badge bg-light text-dark">ساختمان</span>
<span class="badge bg-light text-dark">مالی</span>

                                    </div>
                                    
                                    <div class="clearfix"></div>
                                </div>                              
                                <div class="postinfobot">
                                    
         <div class="information pull-right"><i class="fa-regular fa-clock">    &nbsp;</i> 10 آبان ماه 1401 ساعت 12:10</div>
        
        <div class="information pull-right"><i class="fa-regular fa-user">  &nbsp;</i>شهرام ارمنی</div>
                                    
        <div class="information pull-right"><i class="fa-solid fa-sitemap"> &nbsp;</i>معاونت مالی</div>

                                    <div class="clearfix"></div>
                                </div>

            
                            </div>
                          
                        <div class="col-lg-12 col-xs-12 col-md-12 pb-2 d-flex justify-content-center cardbox shadow">
                            <div class="pagination">
  <a href="#">&raquo;</a>
  <a href="#">1</a>
  <a href="#" class="active">2</a>
  <a href="#">۳</a>
  <a href="#">...</a>
  <a href="#">978</a>
  <a href="#">979</a>
                                <a href="#">&laquo;</a>
  
</div>
                        </div>
                  
                
    </div>
        
        
        
        <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-4">

            
                <div class="sidebarblock shadow cardbox">
                                <h3>دسته بندی ها</h3>
     
                                <div class="divline"></div>
                                <div class="blocktxt">
                                    <ul class="cats">
                                        <li><a href="#">خدمات مشترکین<span class="badge pull-left">20</span></a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#">قبوض برق<span class="badge pull-left">10</span></a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#">رفع حریم شبکه توزیع<span class="badge pull-left">50</span></a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#">برآورد هزینه انشعاب<span class="badge pull-left">36</span></a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#">سیستم جامع مالی(طلای شرق)<span class="badge pull-left">41</span></a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#">سیستم جامع مشترکین<span class="badge pull-left">11</span></a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#">سامانه فنی و مهندسی(سنم)<span class="badge pull-left">5</span></a></li>
                                    </ul>
                                </div>
                            </div>
            

            
  
        


  
        </div>
    <!--    main content row-->
        </div>  
<!--end main body-->
        <script>
        function walkNode(node) { 
    if (node.nodeType == 3) {
        node.data = node.data.replace(/\d/g,convert);
    }  
    for (var i = 0; i < node.childNodes.length; i++) {
        walkNode(node.childNodes[i]); 
    }
}
walkNode(document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0]);
function convert(a){
    return ['۰', '۱', '۲', '۳', '۴', '۵', '۶', '۷', '۸', '۹'][a];
}
        </script>
    </body>
<footer>
    <div class="footer cardbox shadow">
    The Footer is Here!
    </div>
    </footer>

</html>
```

Comment: The footer goes inside the body, before you close `</body>`

Comment: I check multi ways and this is my last try , inside body outside body not working and attached to the body.I need way to set footer end of document .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you want ?

I am using css grid for this. Check the css at the start of the document.
To learn how it works : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout

```css
body {
  font-family: Vazirmatn;
  min-height: 100vh;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: auto 1fr auto;
}

.main_menu {
  grid-row: 1;
}

.main_content {
  grid-row: 2;
}

.footer {
  grid-row: 3;
}


/*End FontFamily*/


/*===========================================================================*/


/*General style*/



.shadow {
  box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.24) 0px 3px 8px;
}

.cardbox {
  background-color: white;
  margin-bottom: 16px;
}

hr {
  color: lightgray;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.pull-right {
  float: right;
}

.pull-left {
  float: left;
}

.green {
  color: green;
}

.red {
  color: red;
}

.gray {
  color: darkgray;
}

.darkgreen {
  color: darkgreen;
}


/*end General Style*/


/*===========================================================================*/


/*breadcrumb*/


/* Style the list */

ul.breadcrumb {
  padding: 8px 16px;
  list-style: none;
  height: 24px;
  width: 100%;
  font-family: Vazirmatn;
}


/* Display list items side by side */

ul.breadcrumb li {
  display: inline;
  font-size: 10px;
}


/* Add a slash symbol (/) before/behind each list item */

ul.breadcrumb li+li:before {
  padding: 8px;
  color: lightgray;
  content: "/\00a0";
}


/* Add a color to all links inside the list */

ul.breadcrumb li a {
  color: lightgray;
  text-decoration: none;
}


/* Add a color on mouse-over */

ul.breadcrumb li a:hover {
  color: #01447e;
  text-decoration: underline;
}


/*End breadcrumb*/


/*===========================================================================*/


/*side blocks*/


/*--- Sidebar ---*/

.sidebarblock {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  border-radius: 2px;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 2px #c9cccd;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.sidebarblock h3 {
  color: #363838;
  font-size: 16px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 20px;
  font-weight: 600;
}

.sidebarblock .divline {
  height: 1px;
  line-height: 1px;
  border-bottom: solid 1px #f1f1f1;
}

.sidebarblock .blocktxt {
  padding: 20px;
}

.sidebarblock .blocktxtlight {
  font-size: 12px;
  padding: 4px 20px 4px 20px;
}

ul.cats li {
  list-style: none;
  display: block;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  line-height: 30px;
}

ul.cats {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

ul.cats li a {
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #363838;
  line-height: 30px;
}

ul.cats .badge {
  background-color: #bdc3c7;
  font-size: 12px;
  color: #ffffff;
  margin-top: 7px;
}

.sidebarblock .blocktxt {
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #363838;
}

.sidebarblock .blocktxt .smal {
  font-size: 12px;
}

.chbox {
  width: 50px;
}

table.poll {
  width: 100%;
}

.progress-bar.color1 {
  background-color: #9b59b6;
}

.progress-bar.color2 {
  background-color: #3498db;
}

.progress-bar.color3 {
  background-color: #e67e22;
}

.progress-bar {
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #ffffff;
  line-height: 31px;
  text-align: left;
  padding-left: 10px;
  box-shadow: none;
}

.progress {
  background-color: #ecf0f1;
  height: 31px;
  border-radius: 2px;
  box-shadow: none;
}

.poll label {
  margin-bottom: 0;
  margin-left: 20px;
}

.poll input[type="radio"] {
  display: none;
}

.poll input[type="radio"]+label {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 31px;
  height: 31px;
  background: url(radio.jpg) 0 0 no-repeat;
  vertical-align: middle;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.poll input[type="radio"]:checked+label {
  background: url(radio.jpg) -31px 0 no-repeat;
}

td.chbox {
  vertical-align: top;
}


/*end side blocks*/


/*===========================================================================*/


/*Tickets review*/

.beforepagination {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

.ticket {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  border-radius: 2px;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 2px #c9cccd;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  padding: 8px
}

.ticket .userinfo {
  padding: 15px 0 15px 0;
}

.ticket .avatar {
  margin-right: 5px;
}

.ticket .co-ownership {
  width: 100%;
  border-top: solid 1px #f1f1f1;
  margin-top: 12px;
  padding-top: 7px;
  margin: auto;
  text-align: center;
}

.ticket .posttext {
  text-align: justify;
  text-justify: inter-word;
  padding-right: 8px;
  font-size: 14px;
  margin-left: 8px;
}

.ticket h2 {
  color: #363838;
  font-size: 18px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.ticket .comments {
  padding: 18px 0 25px 0;
  text-align: center;
}

.ticket .comments .commentbg {
  background-color: #bdc3c7;
  border-radius: 2px;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 6px 8px;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-size: 10px;
  position: relative;
}

.ticket .comments .commentbg .mark {
  width: 10%;
  height: 11px;
  background-color: #bdc3c7;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 36%;
  margin-bottom: -5px;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
  /* IE 9 */
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  /* Opera, Chrome, and Safari */
}

.ticket .views {
  color: #9da6aa;
  font-size: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 29px;
}

.ticket .views i {
  font-size: 10px;
}

.ticket .time {
  color: #9da6aa;
  font-size: 12px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 29px;
}

.ticket .time i {
  font-size: 14px;
}

.ticket .ticketinfo {
  border-right: solid 1px #f1f1f1;
}

.avatar {
  position: relative;
}

.avatar img {
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 0;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.avatar .online {
  background-color: green;
}

.avatar .offline {
  background-color: lightgray;
}

.avatar .status {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 12px;
  height: 12px;
  line-height: 12px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: solid 2px #ffffff;
}

.postinfobot {
  border-top: solid 1px #f1f1f1;
  line-height: 32px;
  padding: 0 0 0 0;
}

.postinfobot .information {
  margin-left: 18px;
  font-size: 9px;
  color: #bdc3c7;
}

.postinfobot .information i {
  font-size: 12px;
  color: #bdc3c7;
  padding-right: 8px;
}

.toTheTicket {
  display: flex;
  height: 100%;
  align-items: center;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.toTheTicket i {
  line-height: normal;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  padding-left: 16px;
}

.tagsintickets {
  padding: 8px 20px 8px 20px;
}


/*End Tickets review*/


/*===========================================================================*/


/*--- Pagination ---*/

.pagination {
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 9px;
  padding: 8px 0 0 0;
}

.pagination a {
  color: black;
  float: left;
  padding: 4px 8px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.pagination a.active {
  background-color: lightblue;
  color: white;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.pagination a:hover:not(.active) {
  background-color: #ddd;
  border-radius: 5px;
}


/*--- End Pagination ---*/


/*===========================================================================*/


/*Menu*/

.main_menu {
  width: 100%;
  height: 48px;
  background-color: white;
  margin-bottom: 8px;
}

.searchbox {
  height: 32px;
}

.main_menu .wrap {
  margin-top: 8px;
  height: 32px;
  margin-right: 8px;
  width: 100%;
}

.main_menu .wrap input {
  width: 40vw;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 995px) {
  .main_menu .wrap input {
    width: 20vw;
  }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 765px) {
  .main_menu .wrap input {
    width: 45vw;
  }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 575px) {
  .main_menu .wrap input {
    width: 65vw;
  }
}

.avt {
  height: 48px;
}

.avt button {
  margin-top: 8px;
  height: 32px;
  border: none;
  box-shadow: none;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-size: 12px;
  padding-left: 16px;
  padding-right: 16px;
  background-color: #1abc9c;
}

.avt .btn-primary:hover,
.avt .btn-primary:focus,
.avt .btn-primary:active,
.avt .btn-primary.active {
  background-color: #1abc9c;
  border: none;
  box-shadow: none;
}

.env {
  height: 32px;
  margin-top: 8px;
  font-size: 18px;
  color: #cfd5d7;
  line-height: 38px;
  padding: 0 20px;
}

.main_menu .avatar {
  margin-top: 8px;
  margin-left: 8px;
}

.main_menu .avatar img {
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.dropdown.avatar .status {
  right: 14px;
}


/*End Menu*/


/*===========================================================================*/


/*header description*/

.headerDescription {
  padding: 20px;
}

.headerDescription h4 {
  font-weight: 500;
}

.headerDescription p {
  text-align: justify;
  text-justify: inter-word;
  font-size: 14px;
}


/*End header description*/


/*===========================================================================*/


/*footer*/

.footer {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 20px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rbsA2VBKQhggwzxH7pPCaAqO46MgnOM80zW1RWuH61DGLwZJEdK2Kadq2F9CUG65" crossorigin="anonymous">
<!--main body-->
<!--menu-->
<div class="main_menu shadow">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="d-none d-xs-none d-sm-none d-md-block col-1 logo  d-flex justify-content-center">
        <a href="index.html"><img src="favicon/android-icon-48x48.png" alt=""></a>
      </div>
      <div class="d-none d-sm-none d-md-block col-sm-3 col-lg-2  avt  d-flex justify-content-center">
        <div class="stnt pull-left">
          <form action="03_new_topic.html" method="post" class="form">
            <button class="btn btn-primary">طرح پرسش جدید</button>
          </form>
        </div>
        <div class="clearfix"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-auto col-lg-9 col-xs-12 d-flex justify-content-center">
        <div class="avatar pull-right dropdown">
          <a data-toggle="dropdown" href="#"><img src="avatar2.jpg" height="32" width="32"></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
            <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">My Profile</a></li>
            <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-2" href="#">Inbox</a></li>
            <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-3" href="#">Log Out</a></li>
            <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-4" href="04_new_account.html">Create account</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="wrap">
          <form action="#" method="post" class="form">
            <div class="pull-right txt">
              <input type="text" class="searchbox form-control" placeholder="[جستجو...]">
            </div>
            <div class="pull-right">
              <button class="btn btn-default" type="button"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></button>
            </div>
            <div class="clearfix"></div>
          </form>
        </div>

        <div class="env pull-left d-none d-sm-block"><a href="#"><i class="gray fa-solid fa-bell"></i></a></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<!--end menu        -->
<div class="container main_content">
  <!--    breadcrumb-->
  <div class="row">
    <ul class="breadcrumb">
      <li><a href="#">نظام حل مسئله</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">مسائل مطرح شده</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">خدمات مشترکین</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <!--        end breadcrumb-->
  <!--    main content row-->
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-8">
      <div class="headerDescription cardbox shadow">
        <h5>سوالات برچسب شده [خدمات مشترکین]</h5>
        <p>این ستاد وظیفه دارد که جهت پاسخگویی صحیح و رضایت حال مشترکین محترم با ادارات تابعه خود هماهنگ شده و درخواست‌ها و پیشنهاداتی که به خدمات مشترکین در ستاد ارجاع میگردد براساس مقررات و آئین نامه تکمیلی تعرفه‌های برق آنرا تا حصول نتیجه پیگیری نماید
          کارهایی که در این ستاد انجام میشود بصورت خلاصه بشرح ذیل میباشد:</p>
        <p>۱ - رسیدگی به شکوائیه جهت اشتراکهای عادی و دیماند<br /> ۲ - بررسی تعدیلات در بخش عادی و دیماند<br /> ۳ - نظارت بر فروش انشعابات عادی ودیماند در شهرستانهای تابعه شرکت<br /> ۴ - بازرسی موردی و اتفاقی از ادارات مشترکین در شهرستانهای تابعه شرکت<br
          />
          <hr>
          <div class="filter">
            <div class="btn-group" role="group" aria-label="Button group with nested dropdown">
              <button type="button" class="btn"><span class="fa-solid fa-eye fa-lg" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                                دنبال کردن</button>
              <button type="button" class="btn"><span class="fa-regular fa-clock fa-lg" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                                تازه ها</button>
              <button type="button" class="btn"><span class="fa-solid fa-chart-line fa-lg" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                                فعال ترین</button>
            </div>
          </div>
      </div>
      <div class="ticket beforepagination shadow cardbox">
        <div class="topwrap">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-1 col-sm-2 d-flex justify-content-center">
              <div class="userinfo pull-right">
                <div class="avatar">
                  <img src="avatar4.jpg" alt="">
                  <div class="status offline">&nbsp;</div>
                </div>
                <div class="co-ownership">
                  <i class="fa-regular fa-circle-check gray"></i>
                  <i class="fa-solid fa-lock green"></i>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-10 col-sm-8">
              <div class="posttext pull-right">
                <h2><a href="#">جا به جایی واحد مالی (بسته شده)</a></h2>
                <p>از لحاظ استقرار موقعیت واحد مالی اصلاً جالب نیست و فکر می کنم باید در جای دیگه ای مستقر بشوند ، بنظرم به قسمت ساختمان شماره 5 بروند بهتر است.یا شاید هم در جای دیگری</p>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-1 col-sm-2 p-0 pb-2 d-flex justify-content-center">
              <div class="toTheTicket"><a href="#"><i class="fa-regular fa-eye-slash fa-2x gray"></i></a></div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="tagsintickets">
            <span class="badge bg-light text-dark">صنعت برق</span>
            <span class="badge bg-light text-dark">ساختارسازمانی</span>
            <span class="badge bg-light text-dark">واحدسازمانی</span>
            <span class="badge bg-light text-dark">ساختمان</span>
            <span class="badge bg-light text-dark">مالی</span>
          </div>
          <div class="clearfix"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="postinfobot">
          <div class="information pull-right"><i class="fa-regular fa-clock"> &nbsp;</i> 10 آبان ماه 1401 ساعت 12:10</div>
          <div class="information pull-right"><i class="fa-regular fa-user"> &nbsp;</i>شهرام ارمنی</div>
          <div class="information pull-right"><i class="fa-solid fa-sitemap"> &nbsp;</i>معاونت مالی</div>
          <div class="clearfix"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-12 col-xs-12 col-md-12 pb-2 d-flex justify-content-center cardbox shadow">
        <div class="pagination">
          <a href="#">&raquo;</a>
          <a href="#">1</a>
          <a href="#" class="active">2</a>
          <a href="#">۳</a>
          <a href="#">...</a>
          <a href="#">978</a>
          <a href="#">979</a>
          <a href="#">&laquo;</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-4">
      <div class="sidebarblock shadow cardbox">
        <h3>دسته بندی ها</h3>
        <div class="divline"></div>
        <div class="blocktxt">
          <ul class="cats">
            <li><a href="#">خدمات مشترکین<span class="badge pull-left">20</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="#">قبوض برق<span class="badge pull-left">10</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="#">رفع حریم شبکه توزیع<span class="badge pull-left">50</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="#">برآورد هزینه انشعاب<span class="badge pull-left">36</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="#">سیستم جامع مالی(طلای شرق)<span class="badge pull-left">41</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="#">سیستم جامع مشترکین<span class="badge pull-left">11</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="#">سامانه فنی و مهندسی(سنم)<span class="badge pull-left">5</span></a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!--    main content row-->
  </div>
</div>
<!--end main body-->
<footer>
  <div class="footer cardbox m-0 text-center shadow">
    The Footer is Here!
  </div>
</footer>
```

Comment: no you have white space after your footer , this attached to end of body not document , use portrait monitor to see what I meant , your answer is like my picture number one.

Comment: Ok, got you... Should be working now

Comment: I like your tricks